# How to bind drowpdown list with one static value and rest from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working with asp.net mvc I want to add a `dropdown list` that holds one static value and other values coming from database

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(model) model.nDepartmentID, 
  New SelectList(ViewBag.txt, "Value", "Text"), New With 
 {Key .[class] = "select1",Key .style = "width: 150px;"})
```

Comment: what is that static value ? something like "Select Country" as placeholder?

Comment: Kindly visit [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to know how to ask a good question. I have updated the title and your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.nDepartmentID, (SelectList)ViewBag.DepartmentList, "Select Any Department", new {@class="select1",@style="width: 150px;" })
```

Your controller Action will be

```
public ActionResult ShowPage()
{
      var deptmnts=db.Departments.ToList();
      ViewBag.DepartmentList=new SelectList(deptmnts,"ID","DepartmentName");
      retun View();
}
```